# Redirecting back to Login Page in Chrome using Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, angular

I have been working on a Angular 2 application which after login routes to other html page i.e loads in  , this is working fine in mozilla but in chrome after login its is loading my page but redirecting back to login page again with "?" appended at end

No errors in console also removed all cookies and all

While Debugging I found that there may be some issue in polyfill.js file of angular but don't know exact reason and solution.

I kms.html page in which is start page 
in app component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, loginComponent, globalFrameComponent],
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', name: 'Login', component: loginComponent, useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/kms', name: 'Kms', component: globalFrameComponent }

])
@Injectable()
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _router: Router) {
        this._router.navigate(['Login']);
    }
```

In Login Component :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'

})
@Injectable()
export class loginComponent {
    constructor(private _router: Router) {

    }

    loginClick(): void {
        debugger;
        this._router.navigate(['Kms']);
    }

}
```

In that GlobalFrameCompnent I have

```
@Component({
    selector: 'kms-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/landing/html/globalframe.html',
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]

})
@Injectable()
export class globalFrameComponent {

//Code i.e properties and method required by view
}
```

Working in IE too, In Chrome only after login  I'm redirecting but immediately I'm getting IIS error page.. HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: You should include code. You will have better chance of getting answers.

Comment: @Ibrahim: added Code

Comment: When navigating write like this: `this.router.navigate(['/Login'])`. Can you reproduce the error in a plunker?

Comment: plunker Code: http://embed.plnkr.co/mH3L5oKgkyRrIqfXSvuB/